# Retriving 3 last records from database for each id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to retrive last three posts from database based on category id, e.g

```
post_id         category_id
   1                 1
   2                 4
   3                 3
   4                 4
   5                 2
   6                 1
   7                 3
   8                 2
   9                 4
  10                 1
  11                 2
  12                 3
```

and I want to retrive something like this

```
post_id         category_id
   1                 1
   6                 1
  10                 1
   5                 2
   8                 2
  11                 2
   7                 3
   3                 3
  12                 3
   4                 4
   2                 4
   9                 4
```

I have made this query but how to limit to return 3 of each category_id?

```
SELECT
     `posts`.`id`,
     `posts`.`title`,
     `posts`.`slug`,
     `posts`.`image`,
     `posts`.`status`
FROM 
     `posts`
ORDER BY
     `posts`.`id`
```

How to limit to return 3 records for each category_id, when I use LIMIT 3 query returns only 3 records.

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results or any of the hundreds of other similar questions.

Comment: @Strawberry correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read 3 new post_id from each category_id

```
SELECT
    p1.`post_id`,
    p1.`category_id`
FROM
    post p1
JOIN post p2 ON p1.`category_id` = p2.`category_id`
AND p2.`post_id` >= p1.`post_id`
GROUP BY
    p1.`post_id`,
    p1.`category_id`
HAVING
    COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY
    `category_id`,
    `post_id`
```

SQL FIDDLE : [LIVE DE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60efd5/1/0)

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`category_id` = 1 ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC LIMIT 3"
```

run it then

```
$sql = "SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`category_id` = 2 ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC LIMIT 3"
```

run that then

```
$sql = "SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`category_id` = 3 ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC LIMIT 3"
```

then that, but don't forget

```
$sql = "SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`category_id` = 4 ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC LIMIT 3"`
```

then you have reached your destination

it is better to just run the queries separate.

Comment: Can you explain why is better to run separate queries then runing all in one query?
Regards!

Comment: Lol there is more than one way to reach your destination as long as the script gets job done correctly. Stop thinking like a robot and gt with humanity.